# how to run ue4 Shooter Game example?

Tags: unreal-engine4

I am using UE4 version 4.12.
I downloaded and created the example game "Shooter Game".

I tried selecting the maps Highrise, ShooterEntry and choosing ShooterGameMode, ShooterGame_TeamDeathMatch and so on. What I got was walking in the level, but not starting game.

I checked [the page](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Resources/SampleGames/ShooterGame/index.html) and found no instructions.

Answer (score 0):

1) You can compile & run it.
2) You can put some bots to example map (you can find it in "...\ShooterGame\Content\Blueprints\Pawns", where "...\ShooterGame" is folder way to your project). And than run this level to see the gameplay.